# Dialogs with regions in a WPF Application using PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, prism

I am developing a WPF-Application using PRISM/Unity and the MVVM approach. So far everything is fine, but I think I have a conceptual problem.

Since I need modal dialogs I implemented a dialogservice, which gets injected into the viewmodels and can be used to open up a modal dialog with a corresponding view. This dialog needs to be navigable ( = contains a region), so that I am able to switch views within the dialog. For this the service creates an instance of a window and navigates to the requestd view in a DialogRegion. This also works.

My problem now is, that at some point I need to open a second modal dialog which also needs to be navigable. If I use my dialogservice I would get a new instance of the dialog window and an exception is thrown, since the region was already registered with the regionmanager (It's done in the code behind of the dialog window). This makes sense, since the regionmanager would not be able to distinguish the regions otherwise, but prevents me from opening a second navigable dialog.

What would be a better approach? I can only think of creating a second dialog window with a different name for the region, but that seems to be a very ugly solution...

---

EDIT 1:
Code for showing a dialog:

```
dialogService.ShowDialog<MyViewModel>();
```

Code in the dialog service for showing a dialog:

```
public void ShowDialog<TDialogViewModel>() where TDialogViewModel : class
{
    IModalDialog dialog = ServiceLocator.Current.TryResolve<IModalDialog>();
    dialog.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    regionManager.RequestNavigate(typeof(TDialogViewModel), Regions.DialogRegion);
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Code in the dialog-window:

```
public DialogWindow(IRegionManager regionManager) : this()
{
    RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, regionManager);
    this.regionManager = regionManager;
}
private void Window_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    regionManager.Regions.Remove(Regions.DialogRegion);
    regionManager.Regions.Remove(Regions.DialogStatusRegion);
}
```

Code in the view for construction, navigation and showing other dialogs

```
public MyViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IModalDialogService dialogService) : this()
{
    this.regionManager = regionManager;
    this.dialogService = dialogService;
}
void NavigateToSecondView()
{
    regionManager.RequestNavigate<MyViewModel2>(Regions.DialogRegion);
}
void ShowDialog2()
{
    // This is where a second dialog window with MyViewModel3 should be shown
    dialogService.ShowDialog<MyViewModel3>();
}
```

---

EDIT 2:
XAML for the Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type localModels:MyViewModel}">
        <localViewsProject:MyView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DialogContent" Margin="10,10,10,10" 
                    prismRegions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static navi:Regions.DialogRegion}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

EDIT 3 - Code for IModalDialog:
I got the idea for IModalDialog somewhere in the web, but I can't remember where. The idea is to have an interface that is implemented by some window-instances and allows for interaction with the user. My dialog only has one content-region (plus a region for status/progress notifications) that can be filled through prism.

Here some code to explain the idea:

```
public partial class DialogWindow : Window, IModalDialog
{
    internal IRegionManager regionManager;

    public DialogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DialogWindow(IRegionManager regionManager)
        : this()
    {
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, regionManager);
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Load Model, when window is loaded
        BaseViewModel model = this.DialogContent.Content as BaseViewModel;
        if (model != null)
        {
            model.LoadData();
        }
    }

    private void Window_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        regionManager.Regions.Remove(Regions.DialogRegion);
        regionManager.Regions.Remove(Regions.DialogStatusRegion);
    }
}
```

So in order to use it I have a static ModalDialogService, which receives a model and some action to be done after the dialog is closed. Something like this:

```
public void ShowDialog<TDialogViewModel>(Action<TDialogViewModel> initializeAction = null, Action<TDialogViewModel> actionAfterClose = null) where TDialogViewModel : class
{
    IModalDialog dialog = ServiceLocator.Current.TryResolve<IModalDialog>();
    if (actionAfterClose != null)
    {
        WeakEventManager<IModalDialog, EventArgs>.AddHandler(
                dialog,
                "Closed",
                (sender, e) => dialogView_Closed(sender, e, typeof(TDialogViewModel), Regions.DialogRegion, actionAfterClose));
        }

        dialog.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        regionManager.RequestNavigate(typeof(TDialogViewModel), Regions.DialogRegion);

        TDialogViewModel model = null;
        var region = regionManager.Regions[Regions.DialogRegion];

        foreach (var view in region.ActiveViews)
        {
            if (view is TDialogViewModel)
            {
                model = (TDialogViewModel)view;
                if (initializeAction != null)
                {
                    initializeAction(model);
                }
            }
        }

        // Attach an event listener to the closing event in order to prevent closing
        // if the form is not in a closeable state.
        if (typeof(IConfirmNavigationRequest).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TDialogViewModel)))
        {
            WeakEventManager<IModalDialog, CancelEventArgs>.AddHandler(
                dialog,
                "Closing",
                (sender, e) => dialogView_Closing(sender, e, Regions.DialogRegion));
        }

        // This event can be published by a viewmodel in order to close the dialog
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<DialogCloseRequestedEvent>().Subscribe((containingDialog) =>
        {
            if (containingDialog == model)
            {
                dialog.Close();
            }
        });

        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to open up a dialog (only one level), and your code looks inspiring. But I am not able to understand about IModalDialog. Can you please show that part of code. It would be great help if you can perhaps share your code sample

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-registering a `Region` with the `RegionManager`. You could reuse the initial `Region` that is registered and create multiple instances of it. These are known as [Scoped Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec42) (under the section *Creating Multiple Instances of a Region*). For example:

```
// You may need to keep track of these scopes
IRegionManager scopedRegionManager = _regionManager.Regions["DialogRegion"].Add(view, viewName, true);
scopedRegionManager.Navigate(viewName);
```

---

### EDIT

I believe it's as simple as changing the constructor of your `DialogWindow` to this:

```
public DialogWindow(IRegionManager regionManager) : this()
{
    var scopedRegionManager = regionManager.Regions[Regions.DialogRegion].Add(this, null, true);
    this.regionManager = scopedRegionManager;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Do you have some further information? The documentation on msdn is not very exhaustive... My questions are: How do I get the regionmanager for a specific scope in another view? How do I get the correct regionmanager in the service (I need it to initiate the navigation)? I need to register the region within the dialog, since the window receives a new regionmanager-instance because it does not find the regionmanager of the shell by searching the tree.

Comment: I think I know what to do, but you'll need to post your code for me to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I've edited my answer, although I could be wrong; as well as ensuring each dialog gets its own region manager scope, I also had to consider issues such as navigation (i.e. what happens when `regionManager.RequestNavigate<MyViewModel2>(Regions.DialogRegion);` is called) and what would happen if you removed views with region manager scopes.

Comment: Thanks George, but that does not work. The problem is, that without `RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this, regionManager);` the region is not registered in the regionmanager and therefore cannot be found. If I add it first, I get an `InvalidOperationException`. I updated m post to show how I connect views and models, because I think, that the is, that the dialogwindow is not a view and therefore the method call `...Add(this,...)` is wrong.